# Being going to school, I met a Mr. Brown. (Is this okay?)

Tags: participle-phrases

> Being going to school, I met a Mr. Brown. (Is this okay?)

I think it's correct. But I think "Going to school, I met a Mr. Brown." is better.

Answer (score 0):

"Being going" is not correct, and there shouldn't be an article before Mr. (unless you introduce the person/character)

> Going to school, I met Mr. Brown.

> On the/my way to school, I came across/ran across/met/ran into/bumped into Mr. Brown.

Comment: There could be an article before Mr. Brown, if he is unknown to the listener.

Comment: But "a Mr Brown" is an unusual construction  (meaning "A person who is named Mr Brown" with the implication that we know nothing but his name.).  Looking at the general level of the OP, I think it is useful to mention this as a possible error.

Answer (score 0):

The first sentence is definitely incorrect. You would not say "Being going..." To express that thought, you would say, "Being on my way to school, I met Mr. Brown." This implies that because he was going to school, it would be advantageous or customary for the speaker to meet Mr. Brown.

In the second sentence, "A" is very very rarely used before the names of people, because it implies that they are distant from the speaker. You will see it in novels from the 1700s-1940s or so, but understand that this is not common now, and it has a distinctly antique feel to it.

Usually you would omit the article completely. "Going to school, I met Mr. Brown."

Comment: Thx. You could hear "a+name": A Mr. Kim (we don't know who he is) is waiting for you in the meeing room.